# Safari push notifications pushmanager cant register

Tags: javascript, api, safari, web-push

I'm using webpush and ran into a problem. I can make it work fine with server and database on chrome. But when I try to register/subscribe from my safari browser it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.pushManager.subscribe')
   (anonym funktion) — Header.vue:99
   r — runtime.js:62
   (anonym funktion) — runtime.js:296
   r — asyncToGenerator.js:17
   (anonym funktion) — asyncToGenerator.js:28
   promiseReactionJob
```

Here's my code for registering the SW on Chrome.

```
notification () {
      var storeId = this.$session.get('user').accessId
      const publicVapidKey = 'PublicVAPID'
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        send().catch(err => console.error(err))
      }
      async function send () {
        var register = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {
          scope: '/'
        })
        const subscription = await register.pushManager.subscribe({
          userVisibleOnly: true,
          applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey)
        })
        await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'API',
          data: {
            subscription: JSON.stringify(subscription),
            storeId: storeId
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        alert('you are now getting notifications')
      }
      function urlBase64ToUint8Array (base64String) {
        console.log(base64String)
        const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4)
        const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')
        const rawData = window.atob(base64)
        const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length)

        for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
          outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i)
        }
        return outputArray
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

using:

```
window.safari.pushNotification
```

instead of

```
window.PushManager
```

should work (didn't test), but only after registration with apple.

as [described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1)

> "You are required to register in the Certificates, Identifiers &
>   Profiles section of your developer account to send push
>   notifications."

looks like Safari is still operating outside of the current standard and requires registration for their service

---

if you want to just filter out in the error and are okay with not having push notifications on safari, you can do:

```
if (registration.pushManager)
  {
   //... do your pushManager.subscribe magic
  }
else
{
  console.log("pushManager not available via web standard")
  // either use apples own push service, do nothing or try local notifications
}
```

otherwise: follow apples description linked above or check out possibilities for polling (not sure if that works) and [local notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications.html)

---

infos found via:

visiting https://whatwebcando.today/push-notifications.html with safari desktop showed me the way to solution mentioned above